# Icon font doesn`t work with localhost but with file:// it works fine

Tags: css, fonts, sass, localhost, mozilla

I downloaded Icon font from Trello and include it into my SASS file but when I open the page using localhost it doesn't work. I`ve tried to use https:// link to font too.

[image: using localhost]

Above in my SASS file I have Roboto font included and it works fine.

```
@import "bourbon"
+font-face("RobotoRegular", "../fonts/RobotoRegular/RobotoRegular", $file-formats: woff )
+font-face("trellicons", "../fonts/trellicons/trellicons", $file-formats: woff )
```

Also I noticed that when I open my page through file:// protocol in Mozilla it works (it chrome still doesn`t).

Console shows one error :

> While loading connection to
>   ws://localhost:3000/browser-sync/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=4Wak5Q‌​FtkPTXAfXXAAAC
>   was interrupted.

But I don't think that's the problem. There are no any 403/404/500 requests. I also noticed that when I open styles in console there is no @font-face for my icon font so browser probably doesn't try to load it. I came over this problem by adding simple CSS file where I wrote @font-face for icon font and it works, but I still curious why doesn`t it work with SASS. I have't any SASS syntax error. I've tried different ways to include it but nothing works.

Compiled CSS looks like this:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:trellicons;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400;
    src:url(../fonts/trellicons/trellicons.woff) format("woff")
}
```

I put my whole project in [github](https://github.com/ArthurKishinets/trello).

Comment: okay, go on? What does your browser console say? Any errors? What does your network tab say? Any 403/404/500 etc? What does your http server say? Any requests for the font at all? And which conclusions are you drawing from this information? You need to tell us about the research you did that has left you confused as to what is wrong =)

Comment: Console shows one error :
While loading connection to ws://localhost:3000/browser-sync/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=4Wak5QFtkPTXAfXXAAAC was interrupted. 
But I don't think that's the problem. There are no any 403/404/500 requests. I also noticed that when I open styles in console there is no @font-face for my icon font so browser probably doesn't try to load it. 
I came over this problem by adding simple CSS file where I write @font-face for icon font and it works, but I still curious why doesn`t it work with SASS.

Comment: please edit your post to put that in, don't add it as a comment. Comments have limited space, whereas your post has all the space you need to go into detail. If adding a normal CSS file works but SASS doesn't, then it's a good bet you got the SASS syntax wrong. A google for "google webfont SASS" gives me http://www.developerdrive.com/2014/05/how-to-easily-use-google-fonts-with-sass/ which looks a little different from what you used.

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation error, **only post the compiled CSS**.  Did you even *look* at the compiled CSS?